# iOS setting a UIScrollView variable from IB shows as nil

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

At the moment I have a UIViewController subclass with a UIScrollView and a UIView inside of it. Below is a snippet of code from the class:

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Scroller : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>
{
    UIScrollView *scrollView;
    UIView *testView;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *testView;

@end
```

Inside the IB I link the UIScrollview to my variable, but when I get to the .m and try setting my scrollview contentSize it shows the scrollView as being nil.

.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    // Initialize of scrollView
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(500, 500);
    scrollView.delegate = self;
}
```

Am I missing an import or anything to get this to be properly allocated?

**Edit**
It may help to know, but if I try to debug the issue and in the lldb check the value of scrollView I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error if I try to continue in the code.

Comment: Where are you trying to set the contentSize? If you are doing it in init or somewhere else before the viewDidLoad then it will be nil because the the scroll view has not been created.

Comment: I am doing it in viewDidLoad. I checked the testView and that has been properly created.

Comment: please add viewDidLoad - also at this point I would double double treble check your XIB links

Comment: I tried something else that caught my eye completely. I removed the link to the scrollView and tried to create it programmatically. What I found was my testView was nil and that doing scrollView = [UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds]; allocated the testView. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes - see my answer below - I will edit it a bit more for you..

Comment: Have you synthesize the scrollView & testView ? as you declared property for these, you must synthesize these in your .m file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue wasn't related to the code, but the debugger itself. I tried doing this in xCode 4.3.1 and was debugging through the application and saw that the proper fields weren't being set both in the xib and in the code. I deleted everything and opened up xCode 4.2 and tried in there and everything worked nicely. After testing in 4.2 I moved to 4.3.1 where it asked me to switch from the GDB to the LLDB. I guess it was just paranoia on my end for not seeing proper results showing up.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
//.h
@interface Scroller : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>
{
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *testView;


//.m
[self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(500, 500)];
```

just to clarify

scrollview without the self. was looking at the iVar - which I assume you had not alloc-ed/init-ed.

The @property IBOutlet connected to your nib is NOT the same as that iVar. In effect you have two variables of the same name - if you get rid of those iVars the property will still get allocated and initialised for you when the XIB is loaded.

Comment: It still allocated to my testView.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that comment - Do you mean scrollView is linked in IB to testView ?!? If so, 1. make the edits above; 2. got to XIB - delete all the old links; 3. Redo the links again

Comment: I removed all the links and tried to allocate programmatically. When I try to allocate testView nothing happens. When I allocate the scrollView testView gets allocated.

Comment: allocate???? you mean like - self.testView = [[UIView alloc] init]; - ??? don't do that.... it will happen magically from the nib....

Comment: I removed the link from it though so that it wouldn't. I wanted to test if allocating through code would fix the issue. It apparently didn't even when I specified what values to allocate.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8877/discussion-between-seb-and-damo)